# Action on Ethereum errors

Tags: ethereum-classic

I am trying to fetch the transaction information from Ethereum and ETC, i have encountered the below errors message .

1. outofgas
2. Reversed
3. badjump destination
4. bad instruction.
   If we have these errors in the transactionhash , do we need to consider them as successful or failure?
   Also if they have internal transactions, what to do? consider them as success or failed?

Comment: `outofgas` for fetching transaction information??? I sincerely doubt that! Please share an actual example of each error, including your contract code, your transaction code (e.g., using web3.js or whatever), and the exact error that you're getting for it. If any hard-coded addresses are involved (of contracts already deployed, that is), then please share those as well.

Comment: If a transactionHash in a block failed with outofgas/Reversed/badjump destination/bad instrauction, and if they have internal transactions , do we need to consider the internal transactions as success or failure? Example: 0x13955895fb60bc615731cff2e26e30a455690a40311e130dfb11be9334a4f1de hash in block 1936257. some explorers mentioned as success. and in some as failed 
https://blockscout.com/etc/mainnet/blocks/1936257/transactions and in otherhttps://etc.tokenview.com/en/tx/1936257/5 . Please let me know which one is correct?